# Unicode strings in Orwell Dev-C++

Tags: c++, unicode, dev-c++

In Dev-C++ when I compile my program with

```
LPCTSTR ClsName = L"BasicApp";
LPCTSTR WndName = L"A Simple Window";
```

the compilation breaks, but when I compile my program with

```
LPCTSTR ClsName = "BasicApp";
LPCTSTR WndName = "A Simple Window";
```

it succeeds; thus the question how to pass unicode-strings to Orwell Dev-C++ in a manner of the 'L' from VS++.

Comment: _"the compilation breaks"_ is a pretty vague description, exactly how does it break? Do you get errors and if so which ones?]

Comment: [Error] cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCTSTR {aka const char*}' in initialization

Comment: You need to change your project settings to build for Unicode.

Comment: With `LPCTSTR` one uses `T("")` or something like that, not `L""`. You should probably read some documentation before proceeding further.

Comment: That's exactly what I did: Reading the documentation and this is where I got it from: http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson01c.htm "Win32 Tutorial" and Windows Data Types on MSDN.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Microsoft's documentation about [Working with Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Very near the start of this you can read:

> To declare a wide-character literal or a wide-character string literal, put L before the literal.

```
wchar_t a = L'a';
wchar_t *str = L"hello";
```

(This information is not Microsoft-specific. It echoes the C/C++ standards)

Then if you consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you have cited in your comment
and find the entry for `LPCTSTR` you see that this macro is defined conditionally upon the value of `UNICODE`:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR; 
#else
    typedef LPCSTR LPCTSTR;
#endif
```

The entry for `LPCWSTR` tells you it is defined:

```
typedef CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR;
```

And the entry or `LPCSTR` tells you it is defined:

```
typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR;
```

You are building your project without `UNICODE` defined. Accordingly,

```
LPCTSTR ClsName = L"BasicApp";
```

becomes:

```
__nullterminated CONST CHAR * ClsName = L"BasicApp";
```

which, by the definitions mentioned, involves initializing a `CONST CHAR *` with an incompatible pointer type, `wchar_t *`. Likewise for `WndName`.

To rectify this error, you must add `UNICODE` to the preprocessor definitions of your project. In the Orwell Dev-C++ IDE, do this by navigating **Project** -> **Project Options** -> **Parameters**; enter `-DUNICODE` in the text box headed **C++ compiler** and OK out. A Visual Studio C/C++ project defines `UNICODE` by default. Orwell Dev-C++ does not.

If you want to write definitions of string literals that are portable between unicode and the ANSI multibyte character set, then [Working with Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tells you how: read the entry for `TCHARS`. The portable definitions of your string literals will be:

```
LPCTSTR ClsName = TEXT("BasicApp");
LPCTSTR WndName = TEXT("A Simple Window");
```